# How to implement a function to effectively traverse through the given data structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I've a data-structure of the following form represented using a combination of list and dictionary in python -

```
data = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "2",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "3",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "5",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "6",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "7",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": "8",
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "9",
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "children": []
    }
]
```

I want to write a function of the following form to retrieve a node from this data structure -

```
get_node(id, data)
```

which returns the node with the passed id, as in -

```
get_node(id="3", data=data)
```

would return -

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "children": []
}
```

I tried the following way -

```
def get_node(id, data):
    for item in data:
        if item.get('id') == id:
            return function
        if item.get('children'):
            return get_node(
                id=id,
                data=function.get('children'))
    return None
```

which takes care of the children recursively. I'm not able to come up with a solution to retrieve from the sibling level nodes.

Comment: Parsing means you have a textual representation (e.g. str, bytes) and *convert* that to some actual first class data object (e.g. dict, list). This appears not to be what you want, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: When you write `Functions.get_node`, does that mean that `get_node` is part of a class? If so, you should decorate it with `@staticmethod`.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for.. Do you just want to get an element (plus the element children) by its id?

Comment: I would like to have children as well in the response as I've specified children in the function's response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is not to simply return the recursive call, but to check if it actually found a node. That way, if it can't find the relevant node in the first child node or its descendents, it will continue with the rest of the children.

(I added some type annotations because I find that it clarifies things, especially with ad-hoc datastructures, but you don't need them to make it work.)

(Also, I changed `spam.get('cheese')` to `spam['cheese']` which is usually what you want, unless you explicitly need to handle the case where `'cheese' not in spam`.)

```
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import TypedDict, Optional


class Node(TypedDict):
    id: str
    children: list[Node]


def get_node(id: str, data: list[Node]) -> Optional[Node]:
    for node in data:
        if node['id'] == id:
            return node
        found_node = get_node(id=id, data=node['children'])
        if found_node is not None:
            return found_node
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the implementation of `recursive function`, here it is:

```py
def getData(id, data):
    for each in data:
        if each['id'] == id:
            return each
        else:
            node = getData(id, each['children'])
            if node:
                return node
```

**Given Data**:

```py
>>data
[{'id': '1', 'children': [{'id': '2', 'children': [{'id': '3', 'children': []}]}]}, {'id': '4', 'children': [{'id': '5', 'children': [{'id': '6', 'children': []}, {'id': '7', 'children': [{'id': '8', 'children': []}, {'id': '9', 'children': []}]}]}]}, {'id': '10', 'children': []}]
```

**Sample Run**:

```py
for i in range(10):
    print(getData(str(i), data))
    
None
{'id': '1', 'children': [{'id': '2', 'children': [{'id': '3', 'children': []}]}]}
{'id': '2', 'children': [{'id': '3', 'children': []}]}
{'id': '3', 'children': []}
{'id': '4', 'children': [{'id': '5', 'children': [{'id': '6', 'children': []}, {'id': '7', 'children': [{'id': '8', 'children': []}, {'id': '9', 'children': []}]}]}]}
{'id': '5', 'children': [{'id': '6', 'children': []}, {'id': '7', 'children': [{'id': '8', 'children': []}, {'id': '9', 'children': []}]}]}
{'id': '6', 'children': []}
{'id': '7', 'children': [{'id': '8', 'children': []}, {'id': '9', 'children': []}]}
{'id': '8', 'children': []}
{'id': '9', 'children': []}
```

**PS**: I intentionally  added output with `None`, it's obvious if the given `id` is not there in the `data`